# What happens if I call GlobalLock(), then fail to call GlobalUnlock()?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, memory-management

In Win32 in order to paste data into the clipboard I have to call `GlobalAlloc()`, then [`GlobalLock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366584(VS.85).aspx) to obtain a pointer, then copy data, then call `GlobalUnlock()` and `SetClipboardData()`.

If the code is in C++ an exception might be thrown between calls to `GlobalLock()` and `GlobalUnlock()` and if I don't take care of this `GlobalUnlock()` will not be called.

It this a problem? What exactly happens if I call `GlobalLock()` and for whatever reason skip a pairing `GlobalUnlock()` call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Question is not only about if or if not you call `GlobalUnlock()`. You must call `GlobalUnlock()` and `GlobalFree()`. Both must be called in order to release the memory you allocated:

```
HGLOBAL hdl = NULL;
void *ptr = NULL

  try {
    hdl = GlobalAlloc();
    ptr = GlobalLock(hdl);

    // etc...
    GlobalUnlock(hdl);
    ptr = NULL;
    SetClipboardData(..., hdl );
  }
  catch (...) {
    if(ptr)
        GlobalUnlock(hdl);
    if(hdl)
        GlobalFree(hdl);
    throw;
  }
```

The leak would be application wide. When you exit a windows application, all allocated private memory is released automatically

Comment: Nope, GlobalFree() should not be called if the data is pasted to the clipboard - ownership is passed to the clipborad and it will release memory once later.

Comment: Yes you are right, if the call to SetClipboardData has been made successfully. But otherwise, you must call both. Post modified accordingly.

Comment: I see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalfree that "The GlobalFree function will free a locked memory object.". So isnt it undefined behavior to call GlobalFree after GlobalUnlock?