# C++ GetClipboardData crashes when an image is copied to the clipboard

Tags: visual-c++, copy, clipboard

GetClipBoard data is a popular function for many to get the clipboard data, but a problem arises when you have a image copied instead of text.

```
HANDLE clip;
if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
        clip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
string text = (char*)clip;
cout << text;
```

That is a code I got off somewhere, which simply prints out the text the user has copied to their clipboard out on the screen. But if an image was copied instead, it crashes. Maybe there is there a way to check if `clip` is a string?

Comment: You can't just cast the `HANDLE` to `char*` - you should use `GlobalLock`. Further, you must use the handle **before** calling `CloseClipboard`. Don't forget to `GlobalUnlock` it before `CloseClipboard`.

Comment: The reason of the crash most probably is that if the clipboard doesn't contain text (CF_TEXT), then you get NULL out of the GetClipboardData(). Later, when you cast this NULL to string, you get the crash. In c++, string cannot be initialized from NULL. Check if the clip is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to move "}" two lines lower to avoid acess to not initialized variable:

```
HANDLE clip;
if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
  clip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
  CloseClipboard();
  string text = (char*)clip; // still wrong line, read lower
  cout << text;
}
```

2) Casting of `clip` to `char*` is wrong. There must be special function for extracting of text (read comment from Igor Tandetnik about it; also I recommend you to read answers on the question "[What happens if I call GlobalLock(), then fail to call GlobalUnlock()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160850/what-happens-if-i-call-globallock-then-fail-to-call-globalunlock)").

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call GetClipboardData on formats that aren't present.  You need to first find out which clipboard formats are present, probably with EnumClipboardFormats, and then retrieve (or skip) the data, depending on whether you wish to handle it or not.
Sometimes Bitmap and Text will BOTH be present at the same time, in which case you CAN call GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT) and be ok. Other times, you can't.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649038(v=vs.85).aspx