# Copy String To Clipboard Memory Leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, clipboard

I wrote a c program that simply creates a SQL Query and copies it to the clipboard. However the program seems to produce a memory leak and crash the computer over time. I cant figure how to resolve this issue.

```
//copies the given string TO the clipboard
int copyStringToClipboard(char * source)
{
   int ok = OpenClipboard(NULL);   
   if (!ok) return MY_ERROR;
   /* else */
   HGLOBAL clipbuffer;
   char * buffer;
   EmptyClipboard();
   clipbuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, strlen(source)+1);
   buffer = (char*)GlobalLock(clipbuffer);
   strcpy(buffer, source);
   GlobalUnlock(clipbuffer);
   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,clipbuffer);
   CloseClipboard();
}

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[MAX_PATH];
  char *p;
  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
    return str;
  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';
  sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));
  return buffer;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char tag[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char startDate[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char startDay[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char startTime[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char stopDate[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char stopDay[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char stopTime[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char query[MAX_PATH] = "";
  char *temp; //point at mins and secs
  char temp2[MAX_PATH] = ""; //hold mins and secs
  char addPMstart[3]="";
  char addPMstop[3]="";
  int morning=0;
  char *slash="/";
  char *hyph="-";
  if(argv[1]) strcpy(tag,argv[1]);
  if(argv[2])
  {
    strcpy(startDay,argv[2]);
    strcpy(startDay,replace_str(startDay,slash,hyph)); //first hyphen
    strcpy(startDay,replace_str(startDay,slash,hyph)); //second hyphen
  } 
  if(argv[3]) strcpy(startTime,argv[3]);
  if(strcmp(argv[4],"PM")==0)
  {
    addPMstart[0]=startTime[0];
    if(startTime[1]!=':') addPMstart[1]=startTime[1];
    morning=atoi(addPMstart);
    morning+=12;
    itoa(morning,addPMstart,10);
    temp = strpbrk(startTime,":");
    strcpy(temp2,temp);
    strcpy(startTime,addPMstart);
    strcat(startTime,temp2);
  }
  if(argv[5])
  {
    strcpy(stopDay,argv[5]);
    strcpy(stopDay,replace_str(stopDay,slash,hyph)); //first hyphen
    strcpy(stopDay,replace_str(stopDay,slash,hyph)); //second hyphen
  }
  if(argv[6]) strcpy(stopTime,argv[6]);
  if(strcmp(argv[7],"PM")==0)
  {
    morning=0; //reinitialize
    addPMstop[0]=stopTime[0];
    if(stopTime[1]!=':') addPMstop[1]=stopTime[1];
    morning=atoi(addPMstop);
    morning+=12;
    itoa(morning,addPMstop,10);
    temp = strpbrk(stopTime,":");
    strcpy(temp2,temp);
    strcpy(stopTime,addPMstop);
    strcat(stopTime,temp2);
  }
  strcpy(startDate,startDay);
  strcat(startDate," ");
  strcat(startDate,startTime);
  strcpy(stopDate,stopDay);
  strcat(stopDate," ");
  strcat(stopDate,stopTime);    
  strcpy(query,"SELECT \n");
  strcat(query,"convert(varchar,convert(bigint,StateTime/3600000))+':'+convert(varchar,convert(bigint,StateTime)%3600000/60000)+':'+convert(varchar,convert(bigint,StateTime)%3600000%60000/1000) \n");
  strcat(query,"FROM History \n");
  strcat(query,"WHERE DateTime > '");
  strcat(query,startDate);
  strcat(query,"' \n");
  strcat(query,"AND DateTime <= '");
  strcat(query,stopDate);
  strcat(query,"' \n");
  strcat(query,"AND TagName IN ('");
  strcat(query,tag);
  strcat(query,"') \n"); 
  strcat(query,"AND wwRetrievalMode = 'ValueState' AND wwStateCalc = 'Total' AND wwCycleCount = 1 AND vValue = 1\n");
  copyStringToClipboard(query);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How have you identified that it is causing a memory leak? Is there, in your analysis, any relation between this and the crash? Can you produce a dump when crashing? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: I guess I haven't identified if it is a memory leak. When the crash occurs I get the error message "QueryString.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close...", QueryString.exe being this program. So I assumed that the program is somehow holding on to some resources, and causing the computer to crash.

Comment: After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160850/what-happens-if-i-call-globallock-then-fail-to-call-globalunlock I'm adding GlobalFree(clipbuffer) to the end of my copyStringToClipboard() function to see if it resolves the issue.